# Wrong unicode character

Tags: fonts

I wan't to add a battery icon in my status bar using FontAwesome, but when I display it it's the home character instead.

I have copy/pasted the character directly from the FontAwesome website into my terminal to see if I can display it and it displays the home symbol !

So I have open my ttf file from a website that displays fonts characters to see if the character is in my file, and it is, furthemore it has the same unicode as my home character.

In my fonts folder I have those 4 files :

```
fontawesome-webfont.eot
fontawesome-webfont.svg
fontawesome-webfont.ttf
fontawesome-webfont.woff
fontawesome-webfont.woff2
```

And I maybe they conflict each others, I don't know.

Also I have no fontconfig file, I kept all my fonts in *~/local/share/fonts* and use `fc-cache ~/local/share/fonts` when I add new fonts.

Comment: How are you choosing the font to display the character from?